# Relationships and querying related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to work out if I have done something correctly.  I have a Department Model.  A Department can have many DepartmentObjectives.  I have also set up the inverse.  So this relationship is fine.

I then have a User Model.  A User can have many User Objectives, this is set up fine.  In my user_objectives table however, there is a link to a department Objective

```
$table->integer('department_objectives_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
$table->foreign('department_objectives_id')->references('id')->on('department_objectives')->onDelete('cascade');
```

So a user objective is linked to a department objective.  Is this something I need to specify within my models?  So should my UserObjectives model have

```
class UserObjectives extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'user_objectives';
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function departmentObjectives()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\DepartmentObjectives');
    }
}
```

For some reason it seems a bit strange doing this.  Anyways, when I create a user objective currently, a department objective is selected and I store the id to the department objective.  So within my view I can do something like this

```
{{dd($objective->department_objectives_id)}}
```

And that will display the id of the department objective it is related too.  How can I get the name of the department objective?

Any adivce appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your tables structure is not very clear, but from what I see I think you need a many to many relation. If **user_objectives** is your pivot table you don't need the *UserObjectives* model, Laravel will create the relationship automatically. You might want to check the doc for many to many relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Are objectives shared accross Users and Departments? Is your case similar to a tagging system in which tags can be added to videos and pictures (2 different models)?

Comment: Kind of like a tagging system.  A department can set objectives which the department want to achieve.  When a user creates their own individual objective, they need to link it to a department objective.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at polymorphic realtionships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
{{dd($objective->department_objectives_id)}}
```

In your view you can call

```
{{ $objective->departmentObjectives->name }}
```

Assuming you have named the name field name.

Comment: By calling $objective->departmentObjectives you are refering to the object(s) you get back from the deparmentObjectives() relationship